# Pretty Logstash Docker logs

Tags: bash, docker, logging, logstash

I'm running Logstash using Docker, and I'm watching the Logstash logs in a terminal using:

```
docker logs -f logstash
```

I have several pipelines, and the output is too messi, there are large jsons (not parsed)  between many other text messages. Is there any way to prettify that output?

I've tried changing the output codec in Logstash `.yml` files, doing:

```
stdout { codec => rubydebug }
```

I've tried `json` too, but nothing seems to change.

Here an example:

[image: Logs example]

Comment: Can you share an example of what you are seeing? Are you talking about the logs of the logstash service or the output of your pipelines? Those are different things, the output codecs only changes the output of your pipelines if you are using the `stdout` output, it has no changes to the logs of the service.

Comment: I've updated the question, it seems everything is in the same log.

Comment: Typical you index that data somewhere like elasticsearch where it's easier to parse and view.

Comment: This is the logstash service log, you can [change the format](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/logstash-settings-file.html#logstash-settings-file) to be in `json`, using the option `log.format: json` in the `logstash.yml` file, but it will not be pretty printed. It will be a json line. Normally you would also use the elastic stack to monitor your cluster and you would index the services logs.

Comment: Please, never show text with images. They are not searchable, not copy-paste-able and much heavier than needed. Copy-paste the text in your question and [format it properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), instead.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet I'm an activist against code as images, I understand the problems with it. But this case is to show the mess I want to order, not the content itself.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but switching to JSON log format actually had the benefit I could use other tools to filter and/or pretty-print the log output.

So, when running locally, I actually use [`jq`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/) to process JSON. Applied to OP's question, I'd use a command like this to pretty-print the JSON logs:

```bash
docker logs -f logstash | jq -Rr 'fromjson? // .'
```

jq explained:

- `-R` - read in the log as plain text (don't assume it's JSON, since some messages/errors are stilled logged in plain text by logstash)
- `-r` - output just plain text if the resulting value is a primitive (string, number, boolean, ...)
- `fromjson` - parse the input as JSON
- `?` - don't fail if the JSON parsing failed but return "empty" instead (special value in jq to explicitly return nothing, not even `null`)
- `//` - if the left-hand side is empty or `false` or `null`, execute the right-hand side
- `.` - the dot simply means the original input (in case of non-JSON plain text being logged by logstash, this will just output the log line as-is)

Example:

```bash
docker run --rm -e LOG_FORMAT=json docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:8.9.0 | jq -Rr 'fromjson? // .'
```

...output:

```json
2023/08/17 07:14:28 Setting 'log.format' from environment.
Using bundled JDK: /usr/share/logstash/jdk
Sending Logstash logs to /usr/share/logstash/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
{
  "level": "INFO",
  "loggerName": "logstash.runner",
  "timeMillis": 1692256478331,
  "thread": "main",
  "logEvent": {
    "message": "Log4j configuration path used is: /usr/share/logstash/config/log4j2.properties"
  }
}
...
```

However, while I think this is an improvement, it depends on how nice logstash is to convert its own format into JSON for logging.

E.g. the following is not 100% JSON, since the actual "change" is buried inside a single JSON string in logstash format:

```json
{
  "level": "INFO",
  "loggerName": "logstash.licensechecker.licensereader",
  "timeMillis": 1692256479070,
  "thread": "LogStash::Runner",
  "logEvent": {
    "message": "Elasticsearch pool URLs updated",
    "changes": {
      "added": [
        {
          "metaClass": {
            "metaClass": {
              "metaClass": {
                "changes": "{:removed=>[], :added=>[http://elasticsearch:9200/]}"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Apparently I am not aware of any log parser that can make sense out of logstash plain text logs.